# VSCode IntelliSense not working for modules when using sys.path.append to add paths

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am adding path that are higher up or in a sibling directories using following code. And I am not getting IntelliSense for modules inside these folders. Any idea how to get this IntelliSense?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The function colorPrint is defined inside LoggingHelper module in Utility folder.

Comment: Would you elaborate more on what needs to adjust settings for the project to properly identify the directories for VS code? And why do you say layout is improper?

Comment: Make adjustments to the [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

Comment: I added folders to "python.autoComplete.extraPaths" but it is still not showing IntelliSense

Comment: not quite sure where my comment went (btw,  i did not vote on your question).   With the info presented it is tough to tell exactly what you have set up as far as directories and python packages.  It looks like you are taking the parent directory of a particular file and then moving up a directory adding that and adding 2 directories under it.  if file  was /usr/me/my_app/main.py than i think you have added /usr/me/, /usr/me/Client and /usr/me/Utility to the path.   you might want to print path sys.path after adding to it to validate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it as following. I am adding parent folder and resolving all modules inside the parent folder. This way, I get IntelliSense

```
HERE = Path(__file__).parent
sys.path.append(str(HERE / '..'))

from Utility.LoggingKotakHelper import (colorPrint, logKotakInfo,
                                        logKotakWarning)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I added images to show that IntelliSense is working and squiggly lines are not there. I have updated answer to also include the code as text.